# Difference between Script Table as for "DROP To" and "DROP And CREATE To" Options

Tags: sql-server, ssms

When I click on "DROP To" Option from "Script Table As" context menu in Object Explorer, it opens up a new query editor window with only "DROP TABLE" statement.

But, when I click on "DROP And CREATE To" Option from the same context menu in Object Explorer, it opens up a new query editor window with "ALTER TABLE... DROP CONSTRAINT" statements and "DROP TABLE" statement.

Doesn't dropping a table also delete all the constraints associated with it? In either case, why are there two different behaviors for same purpose?

Comment: Drop And Create To creates a `DROP` and `CREATE` statement; that's the difference. They do what they say on the tin.

Comment: Because those constraints might prevent the dropping of the table. For example, if there is a Foreign Key constraint, drop table might not work since it refers to another object.

Comment: @Larnu I am not questioning CREATE statements.

Comment: And this matters why? Don't like the functionality? Write your own DDL.

Comment: @EmmanouilKaramalegos : In that case, the "DROP To" option shall also generate statements to drop constraints, shan't it?

Comment: But that's what Drop and Create To *does*. If you don't want a `CREATE` statement why are you using Drop and Create To @HiteshGaur ?

Comment: @SMor The question is not about "does it matter or not"?

Comment: It seems that this question is impossible to answer because you seem to be asking why certain functionality in an application works the way it does. That would be a question for MS and the people who wrote SSMS.

Comment: @Larnu : Oho, as I said "CREAT" statements are fine, the difference is between statements to "DROP" constraints.

Comment: Thanks @SeanLange, may be someone from MS can answer, or if it is an existing bug, they will post it as a link.

Comment: I can only guess that because you are going to recreate the table, it's good practice to `DROP` the constraints too; as the `CREATE` statement recreates everything to do with that Table, including the constraints.

Comment: You won't get an answer from MS here @HiteshGaur, Stack Overflow isn't a Microsoft Community. You'd be better asking on the TechNet forums is you *really* want an answer to your question.

Comment: While this is an interesting question it is not on topic for SO.

Comment: Hmm @Larnu, I agree it is good practice to DROP the constraints too. But the functionality shall be same regardless, shall it not?

Comment: I didn't help develop SSMS, nor do I work for MS, so i don't know @HiteshGaur . It may well be working as designed, to which to the answer would therefore be "No, the functionality shouldn't be the same.".

Comment: @SeanLange : I hope some of MS people are on SO, and explain things over here. whether it is on topic for SO or not, I leave that to SO board.

Comment: Thanks @Larnu, I hope someone from design team can explain more than "No, it should not be same".

Comment: I would be surprised if anybody at MS is trolling the boards at SO looking for things to comment on.

Comment: @SeanLange let's see, my guess is that SO is number one community for all software professionals, and you never know unless you ask.

Comment: @HiteshGaur Not really. The studio aims to provide you factional queries. If you like just to drop a table then drop statement is enough. But if you want to create it also, the studio must make sure that creation will work. That's why it included the drop of relevant constraints.